# Accessing Value of Sub Dict

Tags: vba, dictionary

I can't seem to access the values of the inner dictionary in my nested dict structure...

Ultimately, I want to add the value of the subdict to an array:

```
arrAll(i, intIndex) = dictWF(arrAll(i, 1)).Item(arrWFtypes(intIndexWFtype))
```

(The look-up keys in the outer and inner dict are retrieved from arrays, but they should not be the problem, as these values are recognized as Debug.Print tells me)

Here are some attempts to find my mistake, which also resulted in other errors:

simply brackets, no method/object (error 13: Type mismatch
)

```
Debug.Print dictWF(arrAll(i, 1))(arrWFtypes(intIndexWFtype))
```

".Item" x 2 (error 424: object required) (also didn't work if just used for subdict)

```
Debug.Print dictWF.Item(arrAll(i, 1)).Item(arrWFtypes(intIndexWFtype))
```

".Values" x 2 (found this somewhere) (error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method)

```
Debug.Print  dictWF.Values(arrAll(i, 1)).Values(arrWFtypes(intIndexWFtype))
```

How can I retrieve the value of the subdict?
Is my mistake obvious or should I provide more of the code?

Thank you for your answers!

Edit 02/17:

Here the part where I populate the dictionary:

```
For i_row = 2 To UBound(arrDaten, 1)
    If Not dictWF.Exists(arrDaten(i_row, intADRID) & arrDaten(i_row, intVGID)) Then
        Set subdictWF = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For i = LBound(arrWFtypes) To UBound(arrWFtypes)
            subdictWF.Add Key:=arrWFtypes(i), Item:=0
        Next i
        subdictWF(arrDaten(i_row, intWFTYPE)) = subdictWF(arrDaten(i_row, intWFTYPE)) + 1
        dictWF.Add Key:=arrDaten(i_row, intADRID) & arrDaten(i_row, intVGID), Item:=subdictWF
    Else
        dictWF(arrDaten(i_row, intADRID) & arrDaten(i_row, intVGID)).arrDaten(i_row, intWFTYPE) = dictWF(arrDaten(i_row, intADRID) & arrDaten(i_row, intVGID)).arrDaten(i_row, intWFTYPE) + 1
    End If
    Set subdictWF = Nothing
Next i_row
```

arrDaten is filled beforehand with (printed examples and it works)...

```
arrDaten = Application.Transpose(rngDaten)
```

... and the relevant columns of that range are handed over into this function as indexes and are used in the code above (intWFtype, etc.)

Comment: Please create a [reprex], yes more code would be helpful.

Comment: You could at least share the code showing how you populate the dictionaries.

Comment: Trying to share the relevant part of the long code, but after hoping to produce a minimal reproducible example, it worked in the reduced code... Still don't know how to get the long code working. If I knew which parts still to involve in the smaller example, I would know the error ;)

Comment: @VBasic2008 Shared the part populating the dictionary!

Answer (score 1):

Should be no problems:

```vba
Dim dict1, dict2

Set dict1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set dict2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

dict2("innerKey") = "OK"

dict1.Add "outerKey", dict2

'these all work
Debug.Print dict1("outerKey")("innerKey")
Debug.Print dict1("outerKey").Item("innerKey")
Debug.Print dict1.Item("outerKey").Item("innerKey")
```

Edit: in this line I'd guess you're indexing into the sub-dictionary and not accessing it by key

```
dictWF(k).arrDaten(i_row, intWFTYPE) = dictWF(k).arrDaten(i_row, intWFTYPE) + 1
```

Maybe try like this (with a couple added variables to ease readability:

```vba
Dim k, wfType

For i_row = 2 To UBound(arrDaten, 1)
    
    k = arrDaten(i_row, intADRID) & arrDaten(i_row, intVGID)
    wfType = arrDaten(i_row, intWFTYPE)
    
    If Not dictWF.Exists(k) Then
        Set subdictWF = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For i = LBound(arrWFtypes) To UBound(arrWFtypes)
            subdictWF.Add Key:=arrWFtypes(i), Item:=0
        Next i
        subdictWF(wfType) = subdictWF(wfType) + 1
        dictWF.Add Key:=k, Item:=subdictWF
    Else
        dictWF(k)(wfType) = dictWF(k)(wfType) + 1
    End If
    Set subdictWF = Nothing
Next i_row
```

Comment: Thank you! In a smaller example it also worked for me. Trying to find the important part in my longer code...